# What to do if I have an actor is supposed to have large throughtput?

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor which aggregates some information and processes it. It currently looks like this:

```
class MessageTracerActor extends Actor{

  override def receive: Receive = {
      case MyActor.TracableMessage(msg) => //send processed msg to another place
      case v: Any => //corner-case, has special handler
  }
}
```

The actor is supposed to send the trace of messages which extend `TracableMessage`. But the `TracableMessages` is sent from quite large number of actors and hosting the `MessageTracerActor` on one machine is not quite good.

I looked at [cluster shrading](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-sharding.html), but this seems to not be the case. They said

> Cluster sharding is typically used when **you have many stateful actors**
>   **that together consume more resources** (e.g. memory) than fit on one
>   machine. If you only have a few stateful actors it might be easier to
>   run them on a ***Cluster Singleton*** node.

But Cluster Singleton is hosted strictly on one node which is not scalable.

Maybe there is some configuration option with which I could specify the amount of threads (maybe even nodes) used for processing messages received by the actor?

Comment: I am a newbie to Akka, but won't it make sense to use Akka routers/routees to increase throughput instead of using just one actor.

Comment: @Samar Interesting, I read this article. In the exmaple they create Actors on their own. In case of cluster I will have to manually deploy actors to specific nodes. Maybe sharding is better in terms of it spreads shards across nodes by itself.

Comment: Routers can send messages to routees on other nodes in a distributed system. Here's a link which explains the router/routee strategies to increase throughput. https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/dispatchers-and-routers

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options for scaling message processing beyond a single actor.

## Spreading the message processing in a single node

If the trace message processing is stateless, you can distribute the work between multiple instances of the trace message processing actors using [routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/routing.html). A router is an actor that establishes a pool of processing actors, and distributes every incoming message among the processing actors.

```
// create a round robin style router for actors
val router: ActorRef = context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[MessageTracerActor]), "tracer-router")
```

In the above example, the round-robin style router is used for distributing the messages among tracer actors evenly. This means that you will lose ordering guarantees between the messages sent to the router: message enqueued later might be processed before a message that was enqueued before. Because each message processor sees only an arbitrary subset of incoming messages, stateful processing like aggregations can't be done consistently either.

In order to make the ordering consistent, you have to think about what messages need to be in order. If all of the tracable messages need to be processed exactly in the order they enter the router, the routers wont help you much. However, some of the tracable messages might need to be processed in order in relation to some messages but not the others. For example, your tracable messages might contain a source of the message and the ordering must be guaranteed only between messages from the same source.

Identifying the ordering between messages allows you to distribute the messages among message processors in a consistent manner. Akka provides functionality for this using [consistent hashing pools](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/routing.html#ConsistentHashingPool_and_ConsistentHashingGroup). In the consistent hashing pool, the router distributes the incoming messages to message processors based on hash key mechanism. The messages with the same routing hash key will be routed to the same message processor, which means that you can consistently do aggregations on incoming messages for a subset of the tracable messages.

## Spreading the message processing across multiple nodes

If one Akka node is not enough for processing the tracable messages, you can scale the message processing using Akka's [clustering features](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html). In the cluster, you have multiple Akka nodes connected to each other, working together by distributing work across the cluster rather than processing everything in a single node.

In the cluster, you have distributed version of the tools described earlier available. For both the stateless and stateful routing of messages, you can use [a cluster aware router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html#Cluster_Aware_Routers). The cluster aware router creates a pool of message processors across the cluster member nodes rather than creating them all in a single node.

Besides cluster aware router, you can also use [cluster sharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html#Cluster_Sharding). Like in the consistent hash pool, you need to specify a hashing key for the cluster shard in order to consistently route messages to the correct actor. The difference between a cluster aware router and a sharding is that the shard automatically creates an actor for each key, thus the message processor actor doesn't need to handle messages from different keys separately.

If all of the tracable messages need to be aggregated under the same state, your final option is to consider Akka's [distributed data](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/distributed-data.html#distributed-data-scala) feature. In this feature, the aggregation work is distributed across multiple nodes and joined at a later stage. Note that distributed data API is still experimental in Akka 2.4.

## Other areas to look into

Distributing the message processing across multiple nodes means that there is a higher risk of individual message processors dropping (e.g. network connection failure, node crashing). In order to keep the state persistent and transferrable between nodes, you may want to look into Akka's [persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/persistence.html) feature.